# In TextEditingController field how to fixed label text in top in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

I want to fixed my label text in the top of the TextEditingController field. normality when we write something/ focus on the field then the label text go into the top. But i want to fixed label text in the top. And after focus whole background will change.

I tried but always i found the label move after i write something in the text editing field.
Then i tried to use Column and first child as text and second as textEditingController Field but the issue is after focus on textEditingController the whole backgroud will be change With the text .

Comment: can you include sample  snippet that you’ve tried

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this,

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    floatingLabelBehavior:FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
  ),
);
```

for more info see documentation
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/floatingLabelBehavior.html

Comment: Yes this is a way.
But in this way labelText are placed at the top of the line.
but I want to place the text inside the border